# Hint Form and Focus

Tags: delphi, windows-7, focus, delphi-xe

I am displaying a custom form as a hint. I want the hint window not to get the focus.

`Enabled` property of the hint form is set to `False` and I also handle the `WM_MOUSE_ACTIVATE`window message and return `MA_NOACTIVATE`. Nevertheless each time the hint window is displayed the border of my main window flickers (Windows 7 with transparent borders).

How can I avoid this flickering?

Comment: I suggest you take a look of `THintWindow` (Controls.pas). specially on it's `THintWindow.CreateParams` and `ActivateHint` methods.

Comment: Any hint what exactly is important? Situation is a bit different and I tried most of the things from `THintWindow`, but can't get it to work...

Comment: I mentioned what I consider important (*specially*) in my comment. 
I can only guess without seeing your code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you show your own hint form when you handle `Application.OnShowHint`, e.g. as follows:

```
procedure TMainForm.ApplicationShowHint(var HintStr: string;
  var CanShow: Boolean; var HintInfo: THintInfo);
var
  HintForm: THintForm;
begin
  CanShow := False;
  HintForm := THintForm.Create(nil);
  HintForm.HintLabel.Caption := HintStr;
  HintForm.Left := HintInfo.HintPos.X;
  HintForm.Top := HintInfo.HintPos.Y;
  ShowWindow(HintForm.Handle, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
end;
```

That last line does the trick here with D7 (and with a `THintFrom` as a normal form with default settings, e.g. Enabled = True) on XP and W7.

Comment: Thanks! Seems that I tried to many things at once. I once added an additional `fsStayOnTop` to the form style which seems to cause the flickering. Using `ShowWindow` as you suggest works nicely! +1 and accepted.